# Removing first two elements of a string array in C

Tags: c

How can I remove first two elements of a string array?
I have a code which is something like this.

```
char *x[10];
..............
..............
..............
char *event[20];
event[0]=strtok(x[i]," ");
event[1]=strtok(NULL," ");
event[2]=strtok(NULL," ");
event[3]=strtok(NULL," ");
event[4]=strtok(NULL," ");
event[5]=strtok(NULL," ");
for(i=2;i<length;i++)
{
    strcpy(event[i-2],event[i]);
}
```

I observed that only event[0] has proper values. I printed the contents of event[][] before for loop and it displays correctly. Could you please tell me why this is wrong? and a possible solution?

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the output which you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `strcpy()` in this code. The API [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) will return you a pointer to the delimited token discovered *within the original source buffer after terminating at the discovered delimiter*. Therefore, you're using  `strcpy()` where you should not be.

Your `events[]` array has *pointers* returned from `strtok()`. Just throw out the first two pointers and move the others down:

```
for(i=2;i<length;i++)
    event[i-2] = event[i];
length -= min(length, 2);
```

Note: the `min()` is required to ensure your length, signed or unsigned, never wraps below zero (if signed) or UINT_MAX (if unsigned) in the event `length` is undersized on entry.